# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'

Tags: django

I can't figure out why this error is appearing. I understand what the error means, but not why 'favicon.ico' is appearing in the error itself.

Rolled back migrations, edited urls.py, wiped the database, rolled back code.

Here's the model, if helpful:

```
from django.db import models


class DoxpopCase(models.Model):
    uri_length = 50

    minutes_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    court_payments_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    charges_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_filed_date = models.DateField()
    case_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    case_local_type_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    case_is_marked_expunged = models.BooleanField()
    dispositions_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    as_of_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    case_local_disposition_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    case_local_subtype_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    court_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_disposition_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    events_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_global_type_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    case_actors_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_global_disposition_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    case_local_status_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    court_receivables_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_caption = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    sentences_uri = models.CharField(max_length=uri_length)
    case_reopen_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    # case_county_fips = models.IntegerField()
    # archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.case_number


class DoxpopActor(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['assigned_case_role', 'actor_person_last_name']

    case = models.ForeignKey(DoxpopCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actor_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    actor_person_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    actor_person_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    actor_person_middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    actor_person_name_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    actor_person_name_suffix = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    actor_uri = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    assigned_case_role = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class DoxpopActorAddress(models.Model):
    fields = [
        'address_line1',
        'address_line2',
        'address_line3',
        'address_line4',
        'address_city',
        'address_state_province_code',
        'address_postal_code',
    ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in DoxpopActorAddress.fields:
            val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
            if val:
                setattr(self, field_name, val. upper())
        super(DoxpopActorAddress, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    actor = models.ForeignKey(DoxpopActor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address_line3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    address_line4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address_state_province_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    address_postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)


class DoxpopActorPhone(models.Model):
    PHONE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('CELL', 'CELL'),
        ('HOME', 'HOME'),
        ('PERSONAL', 'PERSONAL'),
        ('WORK', 'WORK'),
        ('BUSINESS', 'BUSINESS'),
        ('UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN'),
    )

    actor = models.ForeignKey(DoxpopActor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=PHONE_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    voice_or_fax_code = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)


class DoxpopMinutes(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(DoxpopCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minute_entry_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    minute_entry_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    minute_entry_type_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import web.views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', web.views.home, name='home'),
    path('search/', web.views.search_results, name='search_results'),
    path('cases/', web.views.view_cases, name='view_cases'),
    path('<str:pk>/', web.views.case_detail, name='case_detail'),
    # path('actors/edit/<int:actor_id>', web.views.actor_edit, name='actor_edit'),
    path('actor/edit/<int:pk>', web.views.actor_edit, name='actor_edit'),
    path('address/edit/<int:pk>', web.views.actor_address_edit, name='address_edit'),
    path('phone/edit/<int:pk>', web.views.actor_phone_edit, name='phone_edit'),
    # path('cases/', include('web.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'

Comment: Can you share your urls.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web browsers will always request /favicon.ico, it's the icon that appears in the tab. For example here the icon on the left of this image is stackoverflow's

[image]

You probably have a URL pattern that matches anything and expects an integer. You should change the pattern to only accept integers `path('<int:foo>/', view, name='your-view')` and if you would like to have an icon you should configure your web server to serve an icon from `/favicon.ico`, you can change the location to serve the icon from using a tag in the `<head>` of your page `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/other-path-to-my-icon/icon.ico" />`

EDIT:

The offending pattern is `path('<str:pk>/', web.views.case_detail, name='case_detail'),` you should change the match to `'<int:pk>/'` since the PK of the case model is an int

Comment: Edited my question to add the pattern that has the issue. You should change all of your pk matches to use int

Comment: The problem is not in your models, but in a view - would be useful to see the view code and know which of the endpoints, associated with a view registered in **urls.py** you hit when you're getting this error. You have 3 views taking `<int:pk>`.